# error in python: name not defined (variable in if statement)

Tags: python

May I know why there is an error that 'the name 'output' is not defined'? Thank you

```
weight = input('> ')
converter = input('lbs or kg: ').lower()

if converter == 'l':
    output = weight * 2.205 + 'lbs'
elif converter == 'k':
    output = weight / 2.205 + 'kg'
    
print(f'converted weight = {str(output)}')
```

Comment: Can you show a example input and output? [edit]

Comment: I get a different error "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" on  `output = weight * 2.205 + 'lbs'`

Comment: u should init "output" variable before if. or keep a else to with output = " "

Comment: Add `else output = ''` or initialize output before the if statement with `output = ''`. The reason is output variable never got created when `converter` is not equal to `l` or `k`.

Comment: @AllanWind yes I am sorry that I forgot to int(weight)

Comment: No worries, I posted a tweaked answer below.

Comment: also ur getting converter in lbs/kg so should be checking "if converter[0] == 'l':" to have the multiplication code to hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `converter` is not `'l'` or `'k'`, then no `output = ...` is never executed.

You can precede the conditionals by

`output = <some default value>`

or raise an exception if no condition was met.

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if the value of `converter` is not `'l'` neither `'k'`? The code inside your conditionals would never get executed and hence `output` would never be assigned.

You should declare `output` before your conditionals to have a default value at-least in case none of your conditions are satisfied like this:

```
output = ""
weight = input('> ')
converter = input('lbs or kg: ').lower()

if converter == 'l':
    output = weight * 2.205 + 'lbs'
elif converter == 'k':
    output = weight / 2.205 + 'kg'

print(f'converted weight = {str(output)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `converter` is neither `l` nor `k` then both conditions are false and hence `output` is never created that's why you are getting this error. To resolve this issue you have to create a variable named output before the conditional statements(`if` and `elif`)

```py
output = ""
# rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak the output a bit to make it work:

```
weight = input('> ')
converter = input('lbs or kg: ').lower()

if converter == 'l':
    output = str(float(weight) * 2.205) + 'lbs'
elif converter == 'k':
    output = str(float(weight) / 2.205) + 'kg'
else:
    output = 'fail'
    
print(f'converted weight = {output}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main () :
    weight = input('> ')
    converter = input('lbs or kg: ').lower()
    try :
        weight = float(weight)
        if converter[0] == 'l':
            output = str(weight * 2.205) + 'lbs'
        elif converter[0] == 'k':
            output = str(weight / 2.205) + 'kg'
        else:
            output = "Invalid option"
    except Exception as e:
        output = "Invalid Weight"

    print(f'converted weight = {str(output)}')
```